# Magento addAttributeToFilter array Value

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, products

I'm getting all products with this code:

```
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addStoreFilter()
->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
$collection->getSelect()->limit(12);
```

and also I added this code to get products with "size" attribute.

```
->addAttributeToFilter('size', '13')
```

And now, I'm asking how can I do that with array. I mean getting products value of size = 13,14,15 like array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make an array

$size= array(13,14,15);

and call in array,

$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('size', array('in'=>$size));

this may help.